# How to fix these warnings "External file changes sync may be slow" and "The current inotify(7) watch limit is too low" in IntelliJ Project in Ubuntu

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14

I am getting two warning messages in IntelliJ IDEA when I am opening my project.

```
1. IntelliJ IDEA cannot receive filesystem event notifications
for the project. Is it on a network drive?

2. The current inotify(7) watch limit is too low.
```

**NOTE: I am using UBUNTU 20.04 LTS**

[image: Warnings Screenshot]

Comment: Is the project located on a local directory? Have you checked the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-2/Inotify-Watches-Limit ?

Answer (score 42):

As shared in [this link](https://robbinespu.github.io/eng/2018/08/25/slow_file_changes_sync_inotify_limits.html):

Add new conf file..

```
$ sudo touch /etc/sysctl.d/60-jetbrains.conf
```

Open the file and add these lines

```
# Set inotify watch limit high enough for IntelliJ IDEA (PhpStorm, PyCharm, RubyMine, WebStorm).
# Create this file as /etc/sysctl.d/60-jetbrains.conf (Debian, Ubuntu), and
# run `sudo service procps start` or reboot.
# Source: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit
# 
# More information resources:
# -$ man inotify # manpage
# -$ man sysctl.conf # manpage
# -$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches # print current value in use

fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

Let’s restart the system

```
$ sudo sysctl -p --system
```

Comment: Wow! This drastically improved my IDE and PC performance. I think this was effecting my whole PC somehow.

Comment: The output of `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` was `65536`. I tried Menu > *invalidate caches and restart* and seems like it's working fine.

Comment: But the file /etc/sysctl.d/60-jetbrains.conf is read only, how you changed it

Comment: @Tefa, by using "sudo" you can open the file in write mode. You have to create it in "sudo mode" as well, as you see in the instructions above.

Comment: Just use sudo vim /etc/sysctl.d/60-jetbrains.conf (or your editor of choice). No need to touch the file beforehand.

Comment: @MKesper your suggestion assumes the user knows vim. My answer allows the use of any text editor.

Comment: @glicerico The editor needs to be started as root in every case, I don't see any advantage in touching first.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OsX users (My googling bring me here), if your project code is in Google Drive on your internal disk, you'll get this warning as well.

I believe it's because, Google Drive has its own file system(FS) which doesn't implement all features of the FS. (for example, you can't create symlink on a google drive)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this will work

run this command

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).